# A function in Apps Script that get data from post API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I want to write a function to get a response from an API
Like myfunction( url , body)

Then give data as a return

Data response
Like otp( url, body)
Response data ( for example '1234')

Answer (score 0):

How about the built in fetch?

```js
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
const payload = { name: "Some name", age: 38 };

fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
}).then((res) =>
  res.json().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I second Paulo's answer.

Another way to write the same thing would be to use async/await:

```
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            userId: '7', 
            title: 'Awesome Post', 
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...' 
        })
    }

    const fetchData = async () => { // allows for the use of await

        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

    }

    fetchData();
```